# HTML form submission across various pages

Tags: html, forms, validation, http-post

I have 4 HTML Pages. In each page I have forms and form elements, but my submit button is only in my 4th page. So how do i try to access the elements i selected in the first three pages without using JavaScript??
For Eg: Consider a feedback form where we have to answer question in 3-4 pages in order to submit the feedback. We click "Submit Feedback" button only in the 4th page so how do the elements from the 1st, 2nd and the 3rd page get submitted to the server??

THIS IS A PROBLEM SHEET FROM MY COLLEGE. HERE IS THE FULL QUESTION

**Step 1:**

Identify a web architecture that is suitable for a survey website. The survey website will start with a brief introduction about the survey, and followed by the survey questions. Each question webpage will contain at most two survey questions, links to previous and next questions and a test submit button. Note that a server script is created for this lab allowing you to test if data are correctly passed to the server when the ‘Test’ button is clicked. However, no data will be saved at the server.

**Step 2:**

Use any text editor on your local computer (e.g. NotePad++), create the HTML for the survey website that contains the following HTML 5 elements. The survey form will be placed between the ... tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html lang="en"> <head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="description" content="Web development"> 
<meta name="keywords"   content="HTML (Part 1 – Content - Form)"> 
<meta name="author" content="put your name here"> 
<title>Web Development Survey</title>
</head> <body>
<!–- Survey content --> </body>
</html>
```

**Step 3:**

Mark up the form content using the elements discussed in Lecture 3. These are

```
- Form <form> ... </form> 
 - Form elements such as <label>...</label>, <input ...>, <select> ... </select>, <text area> ... </text area>,<fieldset> ... </fieldset> and <legend>...</legend>
```

Use other HTML elements discussed in Lecture 2 as needed

```
 - Heading <h#>...</h#>, Paragraph <p>..</p>, Horizontal Rule <hr> 
 - List <ol>...</ol> or <ul>...</ul>, Table <table>...</table>, Image <img ...> and Anchor <a ... >...</a> 
 - Special characters
```

For instance the first question page for the name and sex can be marked up as follows.

```
<form id="survey" method="post" action="http://mercury.ict.swin.edu.au/cchua/webdev/surveytest.php">
    <p><label>Name (optional)</label> <input type="text" name="name" size="20" />
    </p> <p>Gender<br />
    <label>Male</label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value=”M" />
    <label>Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" /> </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Test" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </p> 
</form>
```

- Note that XHTML coding style is used in the above sample code 
  A processing script had been set up at the server with the following URL:

"//mercury.ict.swin.edu.au/cchua/webdev/surveytest.php"

This allows you to test if your form can correctly pass the inputted data to the server. Note that none of the sample data entered will be saved at the server.

You can obtain all the survey information and question at surveydata.txt. Ensure that correct form elements are used for each survey question. For example, checkbox is use for questions that allows multiple answers, while radio button is used for single choice questions.

**Step 4:**

Create a new folder ‘lab03’ under the unit folder on the mercury server ~/hit1091/www/htdocs. Upload today’s work to this lab03 folder.

Using WinSCP, drag and drop the all the survey HTML files from your local machine to the htdocs/lab03 folder. You can name the survey HTML files using the ‘survey##.htm’ format where ## represent a 2-digit number. For example, the first page can be named as ‘survey01.htm’ and so on.

**Step 5: Test and view web pages.**

To view the pages through http, use any Web browser and type in the following address,
//mercury.ict.swin.edu.au/hit1091//

The  is s< your 7-digit Swinburne ID >. For example 
*http://mercury.ict.swin.edu.au/hit1091/s1234567/lab_03/survey01.htm*

When the authorization request dialog pops up, use your SIMS username and password to confirm access.

**Step 6: Validate the page(s) and fix any errors displayed and revalidate**

To validate HTML file, use the ‘File Upload’ interface at http://validator.w3.org. For webpages pages that requires server pre-processing, validation via ‘URL’ must be used

Comment: how do you navigate from one page to another one?

Comment: Just using a next button i mean a submit button which redirects me to the next page. But i have no idea how i can carry my form elements to another page!

Comment: which is your server side language? php? could you post your simplified code, please.

Comment: This is an assignment from my college. Have posted the whole question please see the edited version of the question i have posted

Comment: Please try before you post it.

Comment: I already tried it @RahmathullahMPulikkal i am not able to do it without JavaScript.

Comment: if you are allowed to use php, you can do as in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to submit on every page. Then through some server-side scripting attach the post to the form in your next page until you are ready to process the information.

For example, if you were doing this in PHP you could have something like this on your second page.

```
<form method="post" action="page-3.html">
  <label>Input for page 2</label>
  <input type="text" name="page2Input" />

<?php 
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="'. $key .'" value="' . $value .'" >'; //Info from page 1
  }
?>

  <input type="submit" value="To Page 3">
</form>
```

This will "add" the information from first page into the form for its information to also be send to page 3. Or you could also just put them in a $_SESSION.

There are different ways to do it. This is just one of them. Don't forget to sanitize your input though.